# Printing tasks per task list with Laravel 4 Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, eloquent

I'm trying to display several task lists in one page with their respective tasks. In my controller I'm using the following:

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks_lists = Task_List::all();
    $tasks = Task_List::find(1)->tasks;

    return View::make('tasks.index', array(
        'tasks' => $tasks,
        'tasks_lists' => $tasks_lists
        ));
}
```

Using

```
    $tasks = Task_List::find(1)->tasks;
```

Will return for all tasks lists the tasks appointed to task list 1. So I'm guessing here is my problem, what type of clause should I be using to achieve my goal?

My foreach in my view:

```
@foreach ($tasks_lists as $task_list)
    <h2>{{ $task_list->title }}</h2>
    <ul>
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <li>
            {{ Form::open() }}
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="{{ $task->id }}" />{{ $task->name }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fetching the tasks for one of the `Task_List` models (in your case the one with id 1) you should get them for *every* task_list.

Do this in your view:

```
@foreach ($tasks_lists as $task_list)
    <h2>{{ $task_list->title }}</h2>
    <ul>
    @foreach ($task_list->tasks as $task)
        {{-- etc --}
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

**Attention:** if you leave it that way it will make a query on the db every time you call `->tasks`. You need to use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). This is done by adding `with('relationship-name')`

```
$tasks_lists = Task_List::with('tasks')->get();

return View::make('tasks.index', array(
    'tasks_lists' => $tasks_lists
));
```

Comment: @LucasGomez You're welcome. Make sure to use eager loading though. The other answer kind of fails to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to look for the tasks in the controller, so that can be simply removed:

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks_lists = Task_List::all();
    $tasks = Task_List::find(1)->tasks;

    return View::make('tasks.index', array(
        'tasks' => $tasks,
        'tasks_lists' => $tasks_lists
        ));
}
```

Then, you'll need to get the tasks for each task list in the view, like this:

```
@foreach ($tasks_lists as $task_list)
    <h2>{{ $task_list->title }}</h2>
    <ul>
    @foreach ($task_list->tasks as $task)
        <li>
            {{ Form::open() }}
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="{{ $task->id }}" />{{ $task->name }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

And that should be enough. :)

Comment: Thanks! I felt it was simpler than I thought!